# Question about fixing footer drains with no access

Tags: plumbing, water, basement, footings

House is in Midwest. Built in 1997.

In 5 years we have had water come in at the same spot via the basement floor 2 times. Once during a massive spring rainstorm and once when 4 feet of snow melted very fast. I am looking for some opinions on the best way to prevent this short of destroying my deck and digging out around the foundation of my house.

Backstory:

My backyard slopes towards my house. I have a gutter system tied to the storm water drain that includes a drain in the backyard and perforated pipes connected and buried in the backyard as well. I had a plumber come out and camera/snake that whole system out. There were no real backups found. It seems to be working as intended. The prevailing theory is that that the footer drain could have mud or junk slowing it down when water does get to the house.

My issue is that the entire back of my house has a big deck built on it. There are no clean outs for the footer drains. It looks like soil has eroded under the deck so there is no good slope away from the house. All the drains and perforated pipes I described above start in the yard after the deck. So I have a decent system of moving water away from the house until you get to the deck.

The <= $10K options seem to be...

1. Dig a clean out for the footer on the side of the house. Try to see if it is clogged and snake it or fix any broken sections if they exist.
2. Dig a sub pump system and let the water into the basement to get it out. This does not seem very ideal to me.

Would there be any benefit to pulling up some slats of the deck to add soil to slope water away? I just don't want to tear down the entire deck.

Any opinions/observations would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your deck and the footers?

Comment: Pictures please! Is there a way to go under the deck and dig horizontally for the footer drain? You’d have to crawl and dig at same time

Comment: The point where the the gutter system connects to the storm water drainage system is critical and is the source of a common mistake. Poorly piped systems could, especially in the case of hard rains, cause the gutter system to flow into the footer drain. The larger the roof area that the system is handling the worse the problem can be.  Also not mentioned is where these systems eventually discharge. Is it open ended (street) or a drywell. Drywells can fill up quickly and the excess can end up in the footing drain. Install a sump pump when you have a basement and more so if you finish the space.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar situation. After extensive research I found a drainage contractor in North Carolina who recommends digging up each plank as needed and digging a ditch for channel drain. It looks like their deck in video below had wider planks so easier to dig in that slot after pulling off wood plank. Hopefully yours is wide enough.

FRENCH DRAIN UNDER WOOD DECK, Apple Drains, Charlotte North Carolina
23K views

https://youtu.be/Z-mAzGY8-Zw